# how to fix "invalid instruction" error when running node.js in Docker, with sharp.js lib

Tags: node.js, docker, sharp

When running node.js in Docker, with sharp.js lib I am getting "invalid instruction" error and it exits with code 1.

This is likely related to "libvips" used by sharp.js,
that requires C compiler.
I tried using various base Docker images, and so far all get same error. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Here is minimum reproducible set:

When `const sharp = require("sharp");` is commented out it works.

When it is included, getting this error `Illegal instruction`

Dockerfile

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4004
CMD ["node", "test.js"]
```

test.js

```js
const app = require("express")();
const sharp = require("sharp");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`time: ${new Date()}`);
});

app.listen(4004, () => console.log(`listening on port 4004`));
```

package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-csv": "^4.1.1",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

To build container image:

```
docker build -t test .
```

To start for interactive testing:

```
docker run -d --name test test tail -f /dev/null
docker exec -it test sh
```

then `node test.js`

When "sharp.js" is required, getting error `Illegal instruction` otherwise not.

The comments suggest that this could happen when "alpine" base image is used, but in this case it happens with other node.js Docker images, too.

Hope this makes it a bit clearer.

The same sharp lib and code without outside of container without issues.

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. If you're just running some software, that also wouldn't make it a programming question but more suitable for a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to CPU instructions used by current version sharp.js lib that are not supported by some older processors. Resolved by setting exact older version of sharp.js lib, based on this useful answer here:

[NodeJS: Illegal instruction (core dumped) Error after using sharp library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580821/nodejs-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-error-after-using-sharp-library)

this solved issue

```
npm i sharp@0.27.2 --save-exact
```

Interesting: it now works both with `FROM node`, as well as `FROM node:slim` and even `FROM node:lts-alpine`, but `FROM node:alpine` is **not** supported, it reports missing Python. Still, `lts-alpine` is quite small.

Hope this info can be useful for somebody else, too.